# triangulation of a polygon in Box2d

Tags: geometry, box2d, rigid-bodies

I am interested in creating polygon shapes like a triangle fan and I am not sure where to start

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_fan
http://boxcar2d.com/

Is this one body with multiple fixtures? or multiple bodies connected to a single body ? since it can break off on impact. 
Thanks

Comment: A body with multiple triangle fixtures

Comment: but with fixtures, the fixtures cant break off.

Comment: you can destroy fixtures